# Type 'System.ComponentModel.Component' in Assembly 'is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, object, serialization

When I edit the winform UI design, and save them, an exception occurred.

> Type 'System.ComponentModel.Component' in Assembly 'System,
> Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked
> as serializable.

I have no idea even where to search.

Comment: probably you are missing `Serializable` attribute in your model class.

Comment: @ashwathmabiyan _"probably you are missing `Serializable` attribute in your model class"_ - well no, `Component` is [used in .NET Remoting and derives from `MarshalByRefObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component?view=net-6.0#remarks).  This means that code on both ends of the wire (including localhost) interact with the _same_ object instance _directly_ without the need for serialization.  If Remoting types don't want to participate this way then they can be _serialised_ to the destination but any changes are not readily apparent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to Create Component .. Type is not Marked as Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973506/failed-to-create-component-type-is-not-marked-as-serializable).  If you are making a `UserControl` its quite possible that you have some public properties that its trying to serialise that shouldn't.  See the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes i am using control in form. i tried adding [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)] however still not solved the problem.